# With Google Analytics, How to track how many times an item appears as a result in a list?

Tags: google-analytics

So:

- you have a search box
- you find something
- you see results in the list

I want to count how many times an item (with id) appears in a results list. Is it possible? How?

I'm fighting with custom dimensions, metrics, event. But no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible if you implement enhanced e-commerce.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce

You'd need to set the list field (in the actionFieldObject ) to something identifiable as search.  You could then see thenumber of times that product appeared in a search list.